# React authentication Confirm password Logic how to set i can't understand

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

This react code perfectly work properly without confirm password field .But I need check password === confirm password if its match then password valid . But when I click its going to my google firebase without check confirm password field . How can i make this logic?

I can't add any event handler in my confirm password field. Hopefully someone who expert in react and react authentication resolve my problem.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import firebase from "firebase/app";

import "firebase/auth";

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import firebaseConfig from '../Login/firebase.confg';

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

const SingUp = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        isSignIn: false,
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        error: '',
        success:false
    })

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                // Signed in 
            
                var user = userCredential.user;
                user.isSignIn = true
                let newuser = { ...user }
                newuser.error = ""
                setUser(newuser)

                UserInfoPass(user.name)

                // ...
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                user.isSignIn = false

                let newuser = { ...user }
                newuser.error = errorMessage
                setUser(newuser)

                // ..
            });
    }

    function validateEmail(email) {
        const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
    }

    const handleBlur = (event) => {
        let validCheck = true;
        
        //

        if (event.target.name == 'email') {
            validCheck = validateEmail(event.target.value)
        }
        
        if(event.target.name =='password'){
            validCheck =event.target.value >6
        }

        if ( validCheck) {
            let newuser = { ...user }
            newuser[event.target.name] = event.target.value
            setUser(newuser)
        }
    }

    let UserInfoPass = (name) => {
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

        user.updateProfile({
            displayName: name,
           
        }).then(function () {
            
            // Update successful.
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                <h1>Create an account....</h1>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Username</label>
                    <input required type="text" onBlur={handleBlur} placeholder='Name Please' name='name' class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" />
                    <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">Username</div>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Email</label>
                    <input required type='email' onBlur={handleBlur} placeholder='Email Please' name='email' class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" />
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
                    <input required type="password"  name='password' class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" onBlur={handleBlur}/>
                    <span>password must be geater then 6</span>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password confirm</label>

                    <input required type="password"  name='password_confirm' class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"  />
                    <span>password must be geater then 6</span>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value='Create an account' class="btn btn-primary" />
            </form>
            <h1 style={{ color: 'red' }}>{user.error}</h1>
            {user.isSignIn&& <h1 style={{ color: 'green' }}>SuccessFully login in</h1>}

            <span>already have an account ?   <Link to="/login">sign In</Link> </span>

            <div style={{ height:'200px'}}>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SingUp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is, you are not maintaining any state for the `password_confirm` input. You need to maintain a state for that input and handle the user input event also. Such as,

```html
<input required type="password"  name='password_confirm' class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" onBlur={handleBlur}  />
```

Secondly, I think the better approach is to revalidate the inputs in your `handleSubmit` function. As you have mentioned, if you need to match the `password` and `confirmPassword` (or `password_confirm`), you need to validate this before calling `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`.

Your `handleSubmit` function should look like this -

```js
const isPasswordConfirmed = (password,confimPassword) => {
    if(password && confimPassword && password === confimPassword) return true;
    return false;
}

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if(!isPasswordConfirmed(user.password,user.password_confirm)){
        // password is not matching, you can show error to your user
        return;
    }


    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    // ... rest of the codes
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer.This answer really helpful.100% working.